# How can I focus on an input field when a phonegap page loads?

Tags: javascript, iphone, focus, mootools, cordova

I would like to focus on a text input in a PhoneGap application when the page loads. I have tried the MooTools version `$('entry').focus();` and `document.getElementById('entry').focus()` when the DOM is ready.

This works fine when the HTML page is viewed in a normal web browser, but in the iPhone simulator running PhoneGap, it doesn't work.

Is there a way to focus on a form field for iPhones that forces the virtual keyboard to appear?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of iOS 6, the UIWebView class has a property called "keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction". If you want  to programmatically focus text form elements, set this to false via your phonegap config.xml:

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

The default value is true.

More here: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/calling_focus

Comment: Your answer should be on the top, thanks mate! Worked pretty good.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, this is an intentional limitation of WebKit on both iPhone and Android; only a user touch action can trigger a keyboard. I'm still trying to concoct a workaround, but I'm not very optimistic.

Comment: Did you manage to find a workaround for this? Still doesn't seem to be a solution for it.

Comment: @James: Never did find a workaround. However, the policy has been reversed on iOS6 for home-screen web apps and properly-configured UIWebViews. It's a good compromise, and probably the best we can hope for.

Comment: I did manage to get it working by writing a custom PhoneGap plugin and completely replace the HTML input with a native `UITextView` - not ideal, but it does work.