# How to autofocus react textarea?

Tags: reactjs, textarea

I already try autoFocus or focus(), but seems not work.

```
<textarea autoFocus />

or

<textarea ref="textarea" />
componentDidMount() {
  findDOMNode(this.refs.textarea).focus();
}
```

## edit

`autoFocus` seems work in chrome.

Both `autoFocus` `foucs()` not work in iOS.

Comment: Make sur not using [-webkit-user-select property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752250/ios-workaround-for-manually-focusing-on-an-input-textarea)

Comment: `<textarea autofocus></textarea>` does not work for me in Chrome. The autofocus field does not render in the html.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `focus()` in `componentDidMount` seems to work in desktop Chrome and Firefox.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/jonathanconway/full/RKWdGP).

It seems that [Mobile Safari intentionally suppresses auto-focussing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287478/mobile-safari-autofocus-text-field#7332160) of elements.