# Hard to Bring keyboard on single click on input text which is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

Using jQuery i am focusing the element .
when i run on IOS safari browser It takes multiple clicks on that input text to bring the keyboard.
Below is the code snippet

```
<input type="text" id="txtfield"/>
```

```
$(document).ready(funtion(){
    $("#txtfield").focus();
})
```

Please help me to resolve the problem on IOS device

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30977546/1321167

Comment: @vijayP Tried but not working :(