# Autofocus HTML input when app is opened

Tags: javascript, html, ios, wkwebview, autofocus

I have an iOS web app with a `WKWebView`. I would like an HTML input to auto focus when the app is opened. What I've tried and hasn't worked:

1. html `autofocus` tag

   ```
   <input autofocus />
   ```
2. JavaScript

   ```
   document.getElementById("my_input").focus();
   ```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527639/how-can-i-focus-on-an-input-field-when-a-phonegap-page-loads   ??

Comment: I'm sure that would work if I was making a PhoneGap application, but I completely wrote my own web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in iOS due to security issues. The input can only be focused on a tap event.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I am working on an iOS app with wkWebView and we have it so that every page that loads autofocuses on a specific text field. Is this against Apple's terms for apps uploaded to the app store?

Comment: How do you do it? I've tried to do this for so long and found nothing

Comment: We are using the JavaScript to handle it. The wkWebView is not much more than a framework for our JavaScript.

Comment: I see. That is what we do with our apps too (the WKWebView framework part) What JavaScript is used to autofocus, if you don't mind we asking.

Comment: I've tried this (document.getElementById("my_input").focus();) but to no avail.

Comment: I believe I misspoke; it's not handled by the JavaScript. The text fields that we are wanting to be autofocused are just instantiated with an autofocus attribute 
Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp