# External bluetooth barcode scanner does not trigger an event in Phonegap iOS application

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, bluetooth, jquery-events

I'm building a phonegap JQM application, that accepts barcodes from an external bluetooth barcode scanner. I've used this library: https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Scanner-Detection and it works fine on Android devices. But there's a **problem on iOS devices**. When barcode is scanned, **event is not triggered**. If I add a text input to the page and click on it, everything works fine, event is triggered and also scanned barcode is attached to input fields value, but there must be no input field. **How can I catch this event on iOS?**

Comment: You can get some information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4804590/833188) and you can try the solution proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16900931/833188), using a hidden (or zero pixel) input field

Comment: Yes, i know this solution, but it's to messy and therefore unacceptable in my case...